# Custom list forms in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We are provisioning sites programmatically from a remote event receiver (user enters project information in a list and site is provisioned from code) in SharePoint Online.
We want to provision a list with New, Edit and Display forms customized. Is there any easy way to do this in SharePoint online?

I'm provisioning list this way:

```
public static void ProvisionListProjectStatus(Web web)
    {
        if (!web.ListExists(ProjectStatusListName))
        {
            List list = web.CreateList(
                listType: ListTemplateType.GenericList,
                listName: ProjectStatusListName,
                enableVersioning: false,
                enableContentTypes: true);

            if (!web.ContentTypeExistsByName(ProjectStatusListName, ContentTypeManager.PWSProjectStatusName))
            {
                web.AddContentTypeToListById(
                    listTitle: ProjectStatusListName,
                    contentTypeId: ContentTypeManager.PWSProjectStatusId,
                    defaultContent: true,
                    searchContentTypeInSiteHierarchy: true);
            }

            if (web.ContentTypeExistsByName(ProjectStatusListName, ContentTypeManager.ItemName))
            {
                ContentType itemContentType = web.GetContentTypeById(
                    contentTypeId: ContentTypeManager.ItemId,
                    searchInSiteHierarchy: true);
                web.RemoveContentTypeFromList(list, itemContentType);
            }

            if (list.FieldExistsByName(SiteColumnManager.TitleInternalName))
            {
                FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;
                Field titleField = fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(SiteColumnManager.TitleInternalName);
                titleField.Title = SiteColumnManager.ProjectStatusPeriodDisplayName;
                titleField.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you provisioning site based on any custom site template?

Comment: It's SharePoint Online, so I am provisioning site programmatically with CSOM from remote event receiver.

Comment: Can you show your CSOM code?

Answer (score 0):

You can provision a site with custom list forms by following way

- Create a site like **My Custom Provisioned**
- Create yours list in this site
- Now customize your forms (New, Edit and Display)

Now save this site as Template and  use this template in remote event receiver to create new site.

Comment: Remote event receiver is located in Azure web app (it is a Provider Hosted app for SharePoint Online). Templates cannot be used in SharePoint Online as far as I know.

Comment: I do not agree that template can not be used in SPO. You need the template id to create a new site using REST API , JSOM or CSOM nothing else.

Comment: Can you show your CSOM code? I guess currently you are using Team Site Template Id to create new site. Instead of that Id, now you have to use custom template Id. That's all

Comment: I have updated question with code provisioning list.